# Altering HTML input is messing up my JS setInterval() timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, setinterval

Working JSBin: https://jsbin.com/nijozefoma/

I have a page with a setInterval() box and an input box. To duplicate the problem, try loading the code below, manually type 4.5 instead of 0 in the box, and click the text below.  Then, change it to 9.5. The text should count up every 1 second, but for some reason it's going much faster for me.

Thoughts?

```
<head>

<!-- CSS inclusion -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
Input Box: <input type="number" class="timeSelect workSelect" value=0 /> 
<div class="startButton">
    Change the input to 4.5, and click this text. Then change to 9.5, and click again.
</div>
<div class="secondCounter">
</div>
<!-- Javascript Inclusion -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var  secondsPassed;
function startTime(){
  secondsPassed = 0 ;
  $(".secondCounter").html("secondsPassed is "+ secondsPassed);
}
function updateTime(){
  secondsPassed ++;
  $(".secondCounter").html("secondsPassed is "+ secondsPassed);
}

$(".startButton").click(function(){
  startTime();
  setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
})

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".startButton").click(function(){
  startTime();
  setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
})
```

Every time you hit the `startButton` you start another interval which means that `updateTime` is then run twice.

Either cancel the old interval or update your code so that `setInterval` isn't started twice.

Comment: As usual, writing up the question on SO helped me figure out the answer, and I was just about to delete this when I saw your (correct) reply. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear out timer each time

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var timer,
    secondsPassed;

function startTime(){
  secondsPassed = 0 ;
  $(".secondCounter").html("secondsPassed is "+ secondsPassed);
}

function updateTime(){
  secondsPassed ++;
  $(".secondCounter").html("secondsPassed is "+ secondsPassed);
}

$(".startButton").click(function(){
  startTime();
  if(timer) clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
})

</script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval

Comment: It should probably be [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) instead of `clearTimeout`, and `if (timer)` would be equivalent to `if (timer != null)`

Comment: i had the (timer != null) to try to make it more 'clear'. as this was an easy question.  you could also write is as !!timer && clearInterval(timer)  ;)